# How to start Outlook from within a batch file on Windows XP

Tags: windows, batch-file, outlook, process.start, runas

Good day,

I'm trying to find a way to open Outlook automatically from within a batch file called via the Task Scheduler, but can't seem to land on a method that works. The overall reason I'm doing this is that I'm trying to automate a backup of the Outlook pst file. Outlook needs to be closed to copy the pst file.  I can kill Outlook okay and copy the pst file. I'd just like to be able to restart Outlook automatically when I'm done.

I've tried a number of variations using the `runas` command such as:

`runas /savecred /user:computername\mark "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\OUTLOOK.EXE"`

and

`runas /noprofile /savecred /user:peter-fe7f4dbcd\mark "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\OUTLOOK.EXE"`

These work fine from the command line, but when started via Task Scheduler, Outlook never starts. Windows Task Manager shows the process `runas.exe` as having been launched. It appears to be waiting for something like my user credentials, but there's no way to tell.

I've also tried using the `start` command to no avail as yet.  Using the following syntax results in Outlook starting as a new process shown within Task Manager, but Outlook never appears on my desktop.

`start /d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office" OUTLOOK.EXE`

Note too that this works fine if run from a command prompt.  Also note that my Mark account is a member of both the Administrators and Users groups.

I'd appreciate any ideas you guys might have to get this to work.

Thanks a lot.
Mark

Comment: Who is the task running as?

Comment: Thanks a million David!  I actually didn't realize I could create a task using the Task Scheduler program. I'm from the old school DOS days. Doing as you suggested and providing my Windows password for the task works perfectly. I was adding the task via the command line:

at 3:00 /every:s d:\batfiles\Start_Outlook.bat

So as expected in Task Scheduler this was shown as been created by the System user.  I'm still curious if anyone has a method that would work to start Outlook via a batch file that is run by the System user.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a million David!  I actually didn't realize I could create a task using the Task Scheduler program.  Doing as you suggested and providing my Windows password for the task works perfectly. I was adding the task via the command line:

at 3:00 /every:s d:\batfiles\Start_Outlook.bat

So as expected in Task Scheduler this was shown as been created by the System user.  I'm still curious if anyone has a method that would work to start Outlook via a batch file that is run by the System user.

Many thanks.